# Get two words from URL after a slash in PHP

Tags: php, url, get, preg-match, echo

I need to get two words from an URL. So for example I have the following URL:

http://mydomain.com/alrajhi/invoice/108678645541

I need to get with PHP only "alrajhi"and the number "108678645541" nothing else.

Can you help me please?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Have you made any research on that?

Comment: Why all these tags? Have you tried `preg_match` and `echo` to solve this? If so, can we see your attempts?

Comment: iam just a new to php world :) , can i know how to echo this with "preg_match" function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = 'http://mydomain.com/alrajhi/invoice/108678645541';
$parse = parse_url($string);
$explode = explode('/', $parse['path']);
```

Now you have:

```
echo $explode[1]; // alrajhi
echo $explode[3]; // 108678645541
```

Comment: Thanks :) , but can i know how to do it with "preg_match" , regards

Answer (score 0):

Check out 'parse_url' [(PHP manual)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), a function that divides your url into its components and saves that to an array.